# Port 80 open on server but cannot connect to it

Tags: apache, http, tcp, ssh, port

I have an issue that I have been trying to resolve but cannot figure out what is going on. I have various web servers and they all have apache installed on them. They are all on the same network but one is giving me an issue.

I have servers (.44, .45 and .46)

I can ssh into .44 and ping .45 and .46 with no issues. However when I try to test and see if port 80 is open, .45 gives me this message.

```
 someadminuser@somelocation:/var/www$ telnet 10.0.0.45 80
 Trying 10.0.0.45...
 telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Here is the same test on .46

```
 someadminuser@somelocation:/var/www$ telnet 10.0.0.46 80
 Trying 10.0.0.46...
 Connected to 10.0.0.46.
 Escape character is '^]'.
```

So I ssh into .45 to see the port.

```
 someadminuser@somelocation:~$ netstat -tulpn | grep :80
 (No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN


 someadminuser@somelocation:~$ sudo iptables -L
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination          
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:httpflags: 
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

******************UPDATE******************

I saved my ipv4 table and this is what i got:

```
 # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Thu May 29 14:05:31 2014
 *nat
 :PREROUTING ACCEPT [3416:231940]
 :INPUT ACCEPT [1175:75880]
 :OUTPUT ACCEPT [337:25196]
 :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [337:25196]
 -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
 -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

Of course, there is more to it but this part look suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

So the server is redirecting connections to local port 80 to local port 3000.  Presumably there is nothing listening on port 3000 and that is why you are seeing the "connection refused".

If the working servers don't have this configuration, then you need to remove (or fix) the iptables.  If the other servers *do* have that, then you need to figure out what they have running on port 3000 and why the failing server does not have the same.